# Qgis & processing doesn't links with Grass, r or saga

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-2, arctoolbox

After having formatting my computer (W7-64bits), I have re-installed QGIS 2.0.1-64 bits on it .
But I can not use GRASS, SAGA or R via Toolbox (or Processing). I have checked the path in the Options, and I have tried to uninstall and re-install it again, but it doesn’t work yet.
In the beginning of the re-install, I have a message telling that I QGIS is already installed, but it didn't remain any folder or files link with Qgis. 
I checked as well in the option and plugin setting, but everything seem to be fine (plugin activate, plugin repositories connected...).

Did I install something else than QGIS? did I miss a step, etc.?

Many thanks for help!

Comment: You ask if you need to install something else than QGIS: Did you install grass/saga/r ? You have to manually select this in the advanced options in the OSGEO4W installer

Comment: Selecting QGIS should activate the modules as dependencies as well. At least it did for me with qgis-dev.

Comment: @Curlew: Indeed, I did not activate the advanced interface... Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

QGIS also installs files in your user directory (`.qgis2` and subfolders), and writes some data to the registry.

If re-installing does not help, try the 32bit installation of OSGEO4W. The 64-bit version still has some issues where it does not behave as expected.

---

**EDIT**

After looking at your screenshot given in the comments:

There is nothing wrong with your installation, just click on the `simplified interface` bottom right and change to `advanced interface`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also have deleted this file (.qgis2) before re-install QGIS. And I also tried to install the 32 bit version, but GRASS, SAGA or R didn't work neither.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with the error message to your question?

Comment: Here is the screenshot with the error message when I re-installed QGIS 2.0.1 today, even if I uninstalled QGIS.
But, just after the formatting the QGIS installation worked well, excepted that I could not use GRASS or SAGA via the Toolbox.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/0yGx6.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I meant the error when trying to run GRASS SAGA or R. What are the shields on the icons good for?

Comment: I have no error message, I just have no access to the tools. Here is the screenshot of QGIS when I open the toolbox and the options: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vONBn.jpg

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your installation, just click on the `simplified interface` bottom right and change to `advanced interface`...